# migrations file are not being created in laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I am trying to create a user table on my database, i type in composer:

```
C:\Users\Dell\proTest>php artisan make:migration users                                                             
Created Migration: 2017_04_30_195825_users
```

my .env file db, db username and pass are the same as my db created on my localhost, same with database.php file.

The problem is that it says that the migration has been created, but when i go on my laravel project files database/migrations I can not find the file ?

I have been trying to google the issue for several hours, I did clear the project cache, i did created a new project still not working! Any suggestion ?

when i run php aritsan migrate i get this error

```
    [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrat
  ions)

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = homestead and table_name = migrat
  ions)
```

Comment: what is your project path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the database infos are the same on .env file as well as database.php. I am pretty sure your laravel path its not the same as the editor's path.

Answer (score 0):

run:

```
C:\Users\Dell\proTes php artisan migrate
```

migration files can be here:

```
C:\Users\Dell\proTes\database\migrations
```

Comment: @trance_le
grant permissions for user _homestead_ or use _root_ user in .env DB config; 

also make sure that directory database/migrations is writable for CLI user